# Retrieving Data with jQuery AJAX Without Reloading Page in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I have try to stop refresh page on click on select option but when I stop refresh page then data can not get.

here code

```
echo "<form name='frmtopdevotees' method='post' action='topuser_load.php'>
                <h4>select month  <select id='seldrp' name='themonth' OnChange ='document.frmtopdevotees.submit()'>     


                        $optionsmonths
                </select> 
                <select name='topdevotees' id='seldrp' OnChange ='document.frmtopdevotees.submit()'>
                        <option value=10 $M10>Top 10</option>
                        <option value=20 $M20>Top 20</option>
                        <option value=50 $M50>Top 50</option>
                        <option value=100 $M100>Top 100</option>
                </select>   </h4>               
        </form>";
?>

<script>
    $('frmtopdevotees').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });

    $('themonth').onchange(function () {
        $.ajax({
            var value = $('themonth').val();
                    type: 'post',
            data: {
                topdevotees: topdevotees,
                themonth: themonth
            },
            url: "topuser_load.php?topdevotees=" + topdevotees + "&themonth=" + themonth,
            success: function (response) {
                $('themonth').append(response);

            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

when I remove Onchange = 'document.frmtopdevotees.submit()' then page stop to refresh but not data change.

Comment: what did you tried so far..?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please Explain your problem with code.

Comment: how can i stop refresh page and get data on click.

Comment: topuser_load.php code is here   <?php
$top =  $_POST['topdevotees'];
$mnt = $_POST['themonth'];
header ("Location: topuser.php?top=$top&mn=$mnt");

?>

Comment: your `jquery` selectors are not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Change `name` to `id` in ajax,

```
$('#seldrp').onchange(function(){
   ^     ^
// ajax here                          
});
```

And you have syntax errors in ajax.

```
   var themonth = $('#seldrp').val();
   var topdevotee = $('#topdevotees').val();//topdevotess should be the id of 2nd select box.
   $.ajax({            
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            topdevotees: topdevotees,
            themonth: themonth
        },
        async:false,// this line for waiting for the ajax response.
        url: "topuser_load.php?topdevotees=" + topdevotees + "&themonth=" + themonth,
        success: function (response) {
            $('themonth').append(response);
            $('#frmtopdevotees').submit();

        }
    });
```

Comment: removr this `OnChange ='document.frmtopdevotees.submit()'` in select

Comment: and in ajax success add this, `$('#frmtopdevotees').submit();`

Comment: I will remove on change in select but data can not retrieve.

Comment: success: $('#frmtopdevotees').submit() function (response) {
                 $('themonth').append(response);   error was unexpected token function

Comment: You must be hitting error function instead of success function. maybe thats why nothing is getting displayed.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @AjitKumarSingh, you are corect. Either add erro function, or you can see the errors in console.

Comment: add this line at the brginning of your script

Comment: Add JQuery script file on your page. JQuery 1.11.0 or something.

Comment: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script‌​> use this link then my design page  was remove only show table.

Comment: u mean design is distorted??

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).onchange is not a function this is error will display

Comment: change that line to `$(document).on("change",'#seldrp',function(){`

Comment: I will add this is line in console error Uncaught ReferenceError: topdevotees is not defined

Comment: where is the value for `topdevotees` and `themonth`.

Comment: I have No Idea in Ajax.

Comment: error is Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: yes in console in display error jquery-1.11.0.js:9492 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: here is a tutorial for you, http://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/display-other-data-based-on-dropdown-selection/37679

Comment: niranjan@insta-solutions.com

Answer (score 0):

From your code what I can understand is you want to trigger a server call without refreshing the page (AJAX) whenever your any one the select option changes.

There are errors in the code posted. Following is my observation -

1. There can be only one ID in entire page. You have used 'seldrp' in couple of places.
2. If you want the AJAX functionality, you should avoid calling submit() function of the form.
3. The AJAX syntax is wrong which should be as follows -

   ```
   $.ajax({
       url : "topuser_load.php?topdevotees=" + topdevotees + "&themonth=" + themonth,
       method: "post",
       data: {
           topdevotees: topdevotees,
           themonth: themonth
       }, // can even put this in variable and JSON stringify it
       success: function (response) {
           $('themonth').append(response);

       }
   });
   ```

Now coming to the solution part of it:
I would do this as follows - 
1. Will just listen on the select change in JQUERY 
2. Once a select change is triggered, AJAX call is made and which returns the response.
The modified code is -

```js
<script>

    $('select').on('change', function (e) {
        var month = $('#seldrp1').val();
        var topdevotee = $('#seldrp2').val();

        // call ajax here -

        $.ajax({
            url: "topuser_load.php?topdevotees=" + topdevotee + "&themonth=" + month,
            method: "post",
            data : JSON.stringify({
                topdevotees: topdevotee,
                themonth: month
            }),
            success : function(response){
                $('themonth').append(response);
            },
            error : function(err){
                // handle error here
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
echo "<form name='frmtopdevotees'>
    <h4>select month  <select id='seldrp1' name='themonth'>

        $optionsmonths
    </select>
        <select name='topdevotees' id='seldrp2'>
            <option value=10 $M10>Top 10</option>
            <option value=20 $M20>Top 20</option>
            <option value=50 $M50>Top 50</option>
            <option value=100 $M100>Top 100</option>
        </select>   </h4>
</form>";
?>
```

Comment: yes, I want to trigger a server call without refreshing the page (AJAX) whenever your any one the select option changes.

Comment: You can try the above snippet.

Comment: their is no retrieve data.

Comment: can you let me know what you are getting in your ajax response whether in success or error.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1M801htMZ1ORkYwbnFXZ0pPX2s this is 2 page code....

Comment: I have not idea about ajax

Comment: It might be the case that the url you are trying to hit is not returning something. You will need to put in logs and debug the same from JS and server both sides.

Comment: This won't work. You are using AJAX call and from PHP you are calling header(Location...) function. This gets rejected and nothing will happen. Can you please let me know what you are trying to achieve using AJAX..??

Comment: without refreshing the page and  select option changes.

Comment: See, you will need to return the data which you want to see from topuser_load.php file.