# change word text different color when typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I type in a text box which gives matched data then change the color of text and type second time then change other color then type again then again change color.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/S87DJ/ like this in this enter E,F,G then change color my word like: stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind **[`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)** event handler to the textfield using **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** and inside event handler  change color from an array

```js
var color = ['red', 'yellow', 'red', 'blue', 'brown'];
var i = 0;
$('#text').on('input',function() {
  $(this).css('color', color[i]);
  i = (i + 1) % color.length;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="text"/>
```

---

Or generate random color code using **[`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)**

```js
var color = ['red', 'yellow', 'red', 'blue', 'brown'];
$('#text').on('input', function() {
  $(this).css('color', "#" + (Math.random() * 16777215 | 0).toString(16));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="text" />
```

Comment: Can you please explain more about `.on('input',function() `

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33840424/retrieving-data-with-jquery-ajax-without-reloading-page-in-php solve this...

Comment: @VivekVikranth   .on('input',function() is when you type in  textbox then typing change color on input tag